# Cancelling all pending requesting in angular 4 at a time

Tags: angular, http

I am trying to cancel all pending HTTP requests at at time

I have tried subscribe to cancel but it didn't work for me.

I am unsubscribing using loop of all pending requests now, It is working for me.

But I felt it is not a proper way,anyone please help me on this.

```
    for(let i = 0; i < 10;i++){
   let request = this.http.post(this.url, { }).map(
                    response => response.json()).subscribe(
                    data => {
                    },
                    err => {

                    })
     this.subscriptionOfHttp.push(request)
    }
    OnNgDestroy(){
          for(let k = 0; k < this.subscriptionOfHttp.length;i++){
                      this.subscriptionOfHttp[k].unsubscribe()
        }

    }
```

Like This I am doing now, I want to unsubscribe all requests at a time without forloop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To judge code one has to see the code. Please post your code.

Comment: Yes I have added code, Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.

A Subscription has an `add()`-method to put all subscriptions to an inner array. If you then use `unsubscribe()` all subscriptions will be unsubscribed by the subscription at once.

```
public subscriptions = new Subscription();

// ...

someMethod() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10;i++){
       let request = this.http.post(this.url, { }).map(
                response => response.json()).subscribe(
                data => {
                },
                err => {

                })
        this.subscriptions.add(request);
    }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Lynx, Thanks for the help, one more issue i am facing from the code you provided. Please help me, I have added my doubt as answer.